# How to understand the value of Date property of IUpdateHistoryEntry?

Tags: winapi

I am using WUA (Windows Update Agent API) to check for the installed updates on my computer.
What I found interesting is the Date property value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386400(v=vs.85).aspx) is hugely different from the real installation time, i.e local time. For example,  for one patch "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64-based Systems (KB2789645) ", using WUA API, I see the Date value = '2/21/2013 11:04:30 PM', while on my computer, I found in the EventLog, it is logged as "2/21/2013 4:51:58 PM". I initially thought the WUA API is using UTC time, but if I change the UTC time to local time (I am at Pacific time zone), then '2/21/2013 11:04:30 PM' (UTC) will be equal to '2/21/2013 3:04:30 PM' (local), still far away from the eventlog's "2/21/2013 4:51:58 PM".

Does anyone know what this Date property of IUpdateHistoryEntry really means? According to MS in the above msdn link, the Date property is

Property     AccessType     Description
Date         Read-only      Gets the date and the time an update was applied.

Thanks in advance for your help. I am puzzled by this difference.

Kind regards,

JYao

Comment: I think I figured out this mystery.

First the Date property of IUpdateHistory is indeed using UTC instead of local time.

Second what I see in the EventLog is partially correct. The logic here is that if a patch requires reboot after installation, it will not be logged in the windows envetlog until the reboot is done.

So in my case, after installing those patches, I was asked (by a popup screen) to do the reboot, but I did not do it immediately until I finished my work at hand, that was around ""2/21/2013 4:45 PM", and my computer took about another 5 min to fully come up.

Regards, Yao

Comment: Interesting, worth adding an answer to your own question and marking it as the solution.